# Excel VBA delete blank rows on password protected sheet

Tags: excel, vba, macros, passwords

I am running a macro to delete empty rows if all entries of the row are blank. I have the code however, since the sheet is password protected, a message displays saying to remove the password and unprotect worksheet first. I need the sheet to be locked at all stages but also need to delete the empty rows. If anyone can help me enter this part of the code so this problem is overcome! The code I currently have is:

`heets("Media Plan").Select
    Cells.Select
    Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp`

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should do is unprotect the sheet, delete empty rows and then turn the protection back on.

```
Sheets("Media Plan").Select
 ActiveSheet.unprotect Password:="password"
    Cells.Select
    Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
 ActiveSheet.protect Password:="password"
```

Comment: Thanks that works, if i wanted to re adjust the above code so only blank rows are deleted from a specific range how would i go about this? I need to examine rows B13 to B20, B22 to B26 and B28 to B33.

Comment: You could define a named range that includes the rows you want to examine and then use it in your code instead of the selected cells:

Comment: e.g. if the named range is "ExamRows", then the code would be:

Sheets("Media Plan").Select
 ActiveSheet.unprotect Password:="password"
    Range("ExamRows").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
 ActiveSheet.protect Password:="password"

Note that I haven't tested this code, but something like this should work.